# NAN is not appearing in file after cleaning

Tags: python, pandas

I am cleaning datasets using Python. I used na.values for all the missing value. However, when I tried to export the file into csv, "NAN" is not appearing and it just appears blank space in the column.

I tried clean the missing value in the dataframe using na.values

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv(filename, na_values = ["???", "", "-", "None", "null"])  #

df = pd.read_csv(filename, na_values = ["???", "", "-", "None", "null"])  #
```

Expected result: NAN in the missing columns
Actual result: only blank space in the missing columns

Comment: What's the difference between line 1 and 2?

Comment: same. typed two times. it's mistake.sorry

Comment: Could you copy a sample of the CSV here and a sample of the output please? I just tried it and it works for me

Comment: @ Andreihondrari A Height Length Clamp Bearing Sign 
1212 1212 35353 33434 2.78 1212 
1212 - - - - - 
- - 11 121 34 - 
- - - - - - 
- 34 - - - - 
100 47 484 223 2323 232

Comment: @andreihondrari i am getting above csv file when I convert the same.